# Flutter in_app_purchase purchaseUpdatedStream.listen not working on iOS works great on android

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I am having trouble with buying non-consumable products on my app intermittently. I can usually check out fine and the app will get the purchase details on the purchaseUpdatedStream listener. However,  sometimes the `InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.purchaseUpdatedStream.listen((data) {...code to complete purchase})` doesn't receive an update that the purchase has completed successfully. This has happened in the sandbox and now prod.

Basically, iOS says  I bought the non-consumable, but the app doesn't do anything because the listener doesn't fire. This is happening on `in_app_purchase: ^0.2.2+4`

Has anyone else experienced this behavior before?

Comment: In my case, I do receive the call but before the purchase. Plus there  is an exception "Unsupported operation: consume purchase is not available on Android"

Comment: Hey I am facing same issue in flutter iOS for non-consumable product, have you got any solution?